# upgrading SQL server 2012 SE to 2016 EE for dynamics CRM

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, dynamics-crm-2011, sql-server-2016

We do have CRM 2015 on-prem and CRM Nav, their database is in SQL Server 2012 SE.

Can we upgrade just SQL Server from 2012 SE to 2016 EE without upgrading the CRM version? We would like to do this get benefits of EE for Data warehousing and reporting purposes.

Thanks.